# Qual a diferença entre HTMLCollection, NodeList e Object?

Tags: javascript, html

As vezes eu acabo precisando manipular uma **NodeList**, outras um **Objeto** porém não entendi exatamente qual a diferença entre eles. E qual a relação do **DOM** com eles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **DOM** (Document Object Model) possui vários objetos, como `window` que representa uma janela do navegador, e `document` que representa o conteúdo da página.

Dentro desses objetos, pode haver listas de objetos, que são os **NodeLists**. Por exemplo o `document` pode ter uma lista de objetos `input`, uma `table` pode ter uma lista de objetos `tr` e assim por diante.

Segundo a documentação do *Mozilla* (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/NodeList):

> Objetos **NodeList** são coleções de nodos semelhantes aos objetos
>   retornados pelos métodos `Node.childNodes` e
>   `document.querySelectorAll()`.

Ou seja, coleções de objetos.
Portanto, o **DOM** é formado de objetos, que podem conter **NodeList** de outros objetos.

Exemplo:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('divComParagrafos');
// pega todos os "filhos", incluindo espaços
var child_nodes = parent.childNodes;
console.log("child_nodes.length: " + child_nodes.length);

for(var x=0; x < child_nodes.length;x++) {
  console.log(child_nodes[x].innerHTML);
}


// pega todos os nodes de "p"
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll("p")
console.log("nodes.length=" + nodes.length);
for(var x=0; x < nodes.length;x++) {
  console.log(nodes[x].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div id="divComParagrafos">
    <p>Paragravo 1</p>
    <p>Paragravo 2</p>
</div>
```

Já o **HTMLCollection** é uma array de objetos que aparecem no documento `HTML`. Segundo a referência do Mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection):

> A interface **HTMLCollection** representa uma coleção genérica (objeto
>   array) de elementos (na ordem em que aparecem no documento)

Answer (score 0):

Tendo como referência a https://www.w3schools.com/js, podemos dizer que:

- O objeto NodeList é uma lista de elementos extraídos do documento html. Exemplo:

  ```
  <title>Card Test</title> 
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="card.css">
  ```

  ```
  <div class= "card-area" id = "card1">

      <div clas="card" id="card-1">

          <div class = "front" id = "card1-front"> </div>

          <div class = "back" id = "card1-back"> <img src = "img-1.png">  </div>

      </div>

      <div clas="card" id="card-2">

          <div class = "front" id = "card2-front"> </div>

          <div class = "back" id = "card2-back"> <img src = "img-1.png">  </div>

      </div>      

  </div>
  <script src="card.js"> </script>
  ```

Se no meu script card.js eu escrever o seguinte comando var cards 
 = document.getElementsByClassName("card") o resultado seria um nodeList contendo todos os nós identificados com a classe card.

- O HTMLColection é uma coleção de elementos HTML (div, p, a, img, etc...), já o NodeList é uma coleção de nós, como no caso do exemplo acima, cada card é um nó do nodeList cards.